# (No Root File System)-ergo no install 12.04

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, root, ext4

I have my HDD 1Tb partitioned with fs ext4.
Previously I was booting from the 2TB Hard Drive...I disconnected that.
Now I want a clean install 12.04 but cannot figure out "Root File System" ("/")
Crazy...had the same problem 2 years ago...two weeks then...I should have written down the answer!
Can anyone help an old man?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the manual partitioning option - something else I think it is called.

Select the partition you want to install in - Edit - in new window select / from the dropdown - format as you wish.

Exit that back to the partition list.

Comment: I appreciate that, "forestpiskie" but it didn't ever work for me...meaning the install menu would never get me the options.  I ended up saving all my data to externals and reformatting to install ("use entire disk") It was the only way I could get it to work...after exhaustive research.